# guide me in dividing the number by 10 and later converting into a string

Tags: c, buffer, arrays, itoa

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int num = 255;
num = num / 10;
char buf[5];
itoa(num, buf,10);
printf("%s", buf);
return 0.
}
```

I am trying to divide the integer number by 10 but I am getting a solution of 25 ( I should get 25.5). Later I am converting this into string by integer to ASCII function. I have problem to divide that number by 10.

Comment: integer does not have a decimal point. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You need to start by understanding what an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) is.

Comment: There have been some answers for your question, please accept one.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a float variable to get floating point results.

try

```
float num = 255;
num = num / 10;
```

Comment: Or, more idiomatically, `num /= 10;`

Comment: later how to convert into string ??

Answer (score 1):

When storing a floating value to an integer the decimal part is thrown away. So in `num = num / 10;` num will be 25 because it is an int.

Comment: if I use double insteads of int, then how to convert into string ?#

Comment: @chux `float` is automatically upcast to `double`. `%lg` is not a valid format specifier

Comment: @Tom Tanner, Yes of course you are correct.  I was thinking of scanf().

Answer (score 1):

An integer divided by an integer is an integer, so you get 25 as a result. You need to cast divisor or denominator to float or double first.

To output a float to console you can use `printf` with `%f`, `%F`, `%e`, `%E`, `%g` or `%G` format string. You might also want to specify a width and precision (see [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)).

If you really need a string buffer, you can use `sprintf` to write the result to a buffer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num = 255f;
    num = num / 10;
    printf("%f\n", num);
    return 0.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buffer[20];

void main() {
    float num = 255;
    num = num / 10;

    sprintf(buffer, "%g", num );

    printf("%s",buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, num is (as pointed out) an integer, so cannot take fractional values.

Secondly, itoa is not standard. You should use snprintf (which is not only standard, it is not susceptible to buffer overflows).

So:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num = 255;
    num = num / 10;

    char buf[5];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%g", num);
    printf("%s", buf);
    return 0.
}
```

will do what you want.